# Client is not receiving message from server in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, client-server

My server wants to send to the clients a message on connection. Then the client sends a  message to the server .

My code is working fine when the client sends message to the server **but the initial message that the server should send on connection is not received by the client.**

This is my little code :)

**server**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
  io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { log: false }),
  fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8001);

function handler(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client1.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading client1.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("running time");
  socket.emit("serverMessage","server says hi");

  socket.on('clientMessage', function () {
       console.log("client message recieved");
  });      
});
```

**client**

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
       <script>
         socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8001");
          socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
               socket.on("serverMessage", function(d) {
               console.log("server send a message ");
              });          
         });
        function send() {
            socket.emit('clientMessage', "Test Message From Client");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="send()" >send</button>

</body>
```

Please any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simple error in your client code. There is no event named `connection` for client. Instead the name is `connect`. Do this in client:

```
<script>
     socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8001");
</script>
<script>
socket.on('connect', function(socket) {
    socket.on("serverMessage", function(d) {
    // you can alert something here like alert(d)
    console.log("server send a message ");
    });          
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks @M Omary for the answer :) Can you direct me to good tutorials on socket.io

Comment: Well, I learned about socket.io from github https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki and their official site https://socket.io and you can just google socket.io tutorials and you'll find great stuff there

Comment: And one thing I forgot, you can also do it like this outside scope of 'connect' event:
 socket.on('connect',function(){alert('Test');});
socket.on('serverMessage',function(data){alert('data');});

Comment: Thanks!! I was lost in google, it was all this simple.